# Does Oracle have a means to show query execution plans like Sybase 'showplan'?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I am a Sybase DBA/performance optimizer and was asked to look into the performance of some SQL queries on Oracle and see what the problems are and why it is slow.  Is there a showplan similar to Sybase?  I need to get the number of physical i/o's and logical i/o's, table scans and indexes the query or stored procedure uses.

I used to use Embarcadero and I don't have that anymore.

Comment: Put your question in the title; do not introduce yourself to us in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explain Plan and/or AutoTrace is the Oracle Equivalent which will give you the possible execution plan that Oracle will use if you execute the Query.

In SQLPLUS you could do this..

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly;

SQL> select * from scott.emp;

14 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   518 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   518 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          8  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       1415  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        381  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         14  rows processed
```

Here are various other options available depending on the level of detail and your specific scenario..

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/SQLTrace10046TrcsessAndTkprof10g.php

Comment: Is there someplace I can read about that? Any samples? Like I want to show the plans for SELECT * FROM a, b where a.field = b.field.  Both trace and query plan

Comment: Saro - Updated my post above before I saw your comment :). If you want to trace an entire session (may be your complete execution of one procedure), look at the link that I provided below.

Comment: I got this message "Traceonly option is currently not supported".  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: which version of Oracle and SQLPLUS are you using..? Are you doing this in SQLPLUS or any other tool?

Comment: SQL developer  Version 3.0.04

Comment: There seems to be an ICON for doing that. Check this. I haven't used SQL Developer myself, so Don't know the exact location. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12152/intro.htm#CHDEJJDB

Comment: can the downvoter care to comment why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if all of that is available in it, but [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) lets you put a query in and hit Explain Plan to see the execution plan. That includes what it's going to do and any indexes it's using.

It's a free tool, so give it a try. :)

Comment: I have sql developer.  I was unaware that you can do that.  So how do I do this exaclty.  Place my code and push which bottom/options?Thanks

Comment: Put your query into the command window at the top of the worksheet. One of the buttons is Explain Plan. In my copy it's the fourth button on the worksheet.

Comment: Also - you might want to use the link I included to get the current version. Version 3 (the current one) is a fair bit more featured then the version 1 client that Oracle ships with some of their stuff.